# Made a CRUD class, then create a Python testing script in Jupyter Notebooks that imports my CRUD Python class to test CRUD functionality

Tags: mongodb, jupyter, crud

I don't think it's a server issue but I tried fixing server timing, I don't know where else to turn to at this point. I tried every option and stack overflow is my last option. Point out what I am doing wrong or any advice that could potentially resolve this issue. Below is my py file and the jupyter code below that is a ipynb file.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        USER = 'private'
        PASS = 'private'
        HOST = 'private'
        PORT = private
        DB = 'aac'
        COL = 'animals'

        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d' % (USER, PASS, HOST, PORT), server_selection_timeout=60)
        if not self.client:
            raise Exception("Failed to connect to MongoDB database")
        self.database = self.client['%s' % (DB)]
        self.collection = self.database['%s' % (COL)]

    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.collection.insert_one(data)
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save because the data parameter is empty")

    def read(self, query):
        try:
            cursor = self.collection.find(query)
            return list(cursor)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading documents: {e}")
            return []

    #def update(self, query, update_data):
        #try:
            #result = self.collection.update_many(query, {"$set": update_data})
            #return result.modified_count
        #except Exception as e:
            #print(f"Error updating documents: {e}")
            #return 0

    #def delete(self, query):
        #try:
            #result = self.collection.delete_many(query)
            #return result.deleted_count
        #except Exception as e:
            #print(f"Error deleting documents: {e}")
            #return 0
```

For jupyter:

```py
from CRUD_Modules import AnimalShelter  

USER = 'private'
PASS = 'private'
HOST = 'private'
PORT = private
DB = 'aac'
COL = 'animals'

# Instantiate the AnimalShelter class
animal_shelter = AnimalShelter()

# Example data to insert
data_to_insert = {
    'name': 'Shadow',
    'species': 'Dog',
    'age': 3
}

# Test create method
create_result = animal_shelter.create(data_to_insert)
print(f"create Result: {create_result}")

# Test read method
query_to_read = {'name': 'Shadow'}
read_result = animal_shelter.read(query_to_read)
print(f"Read Result: {read_result}")
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is _not working_. _"I don't think it's a server issue"_ what issue is not a server issue?